# Replace hardcoded list of numbers with dynamic array length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to work out how to replace the values 1,2 and 3 
inside this GUI interface with a range of numbers based on simply how many objects there are in an array, so that it dynamically keeps track of it without me having to hardcore it in everytime the array is updated.  [image]

What is preventing me from simply using an array with numbers itself is that each of the numbers is an object inside of this GUI.
The line of code is this.

```
gui.add(data, 'system', {
  "1": 0,
  "2": 1,
  "3": 2
})
```

Suppose I am using any random array holding any random information like so:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i<51;i++){
    arr.push("element");}
```

There are 51 elements in this array and what I'm going for is that the above array holding these elements is used to output the numbers "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" (divided by 10 while still having the 1 leftover) with the GUI interface not breaking down on me. The reason I want it to be divided by 10 is because I don't want to have 51 elements clickable but rather 6 because that's more manageable.

What should I do or look into? Thanks. The fiddle with my code is this. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7ahdtv1f/)

EDIT: It's a relatively difficult question, so I'll try to be more clear. I have the numerical values 1,2,3 hardcoded in this object:

```
gui.add(data, 'system', {
  "1": 0,
  "2": 1,
  "3": 2
}).name('system #').onChange(function(value) {
  updateSets(value);
});
```

But what I'm trying to achieve is so that that I don't need to write in the "1", "2", "3" but that it looks to an array's length (which if it holds 3 elements) it'll write them in in the object for me. But if an array has 51 elements, I don't want to have 51 numbers under the system object, but that it divides it by 10 so that I have 6. Not 5, because I have the 1 leftover.

Comment: Please be more clear with what you want. I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Which object are you trying to parse? `sets`? Or object passed to `gui.add()` at third parameter?

Comment: You don't need to look to `sets`. I'm referring to `systems` object. There it passes those numbers that it has written into it. I have edited my question to clarify some things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to create an object having equal amount of properties and values to `.length` of an array.

Create a plain object. Utilize `Object.entries()`, `for..of` loop to set properties, values of object up to variable `n`.

You can use `Array.prototype.slice()` to get `n` through `x` properties of values from initially created object.

```js
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
  arr.push("element");
}

var obj = arr.reduce(function(obj, element, index) {
  obj[index + 1] = index;
  return obj
}, {});

function getObjProps(from, to, obj, res) {
  let it = void 0;
  if (from) {
    it = Object.entries(obj).slice(from, to);
  } else {
    it = Object.entries(obj);
  }
  for (let [key, value] of it) {
    if (+key <= to) {
      res[key] = value;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  };

  return res
}


var curr = getObjProps(null, 6, obj, {});

console.log(curr);

var next = getObjProps(6, 12, obj, {});

console.log(next);

for (let i = 12; i < arr.length; i += 6) {
  console.log(getObjProps(i, i + 6, obj, {}))
}
```

Comment: That looks great! Hard to grasp but great. Can you implement that into the fiddle in the question so that the system object shows that what's in the for loop?

Comment: @TheNuttyStudent _"Can you implement that into the fiddle in the question so that the system object shows that what's in the for loop?"_ Not entirely sure what is occurring at jsfiddle. Though you should be able to implement the patterns at jsfiddle to meet requirement. For example, substituting `curr` for third parameter at `gui.add(data, 'system', curr)`. Or trying `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 6) {
   gui.add(data, 'system', getObjProps(i, i + 6, obj, {}))
}`.  `if` condition at `for..of` loop where `it` is defined could probably adjusted to accept `0` as parameter to `.slice()`

Comment: @TheNuttyStudent https://jsfiddle.net/7ahdtv1f/2/ , https://jsfiddle.net/7ahdtv1f/3/